# After Unmute phone when call came only vibrate phone, not able to play ringtone

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-audiomanager, phone-state-listener

I'm building an Android app that **unmute phone** when an **Incoming call came** in phone.

I use `BroadcastReceiver` to receive incoming call events. I **switch** phone from **mute mode** to **Ring Mode** when `BroadcastReceiver` receive **incoming call events**.

And expect Phone will **vibrate and Play ringtone**.

But Phone only **vibrate**, **can't play ringtone though phone ring set to max sound**.

I found many apps on play store those can unmute before call and play ringtone and vibrate both. Example: [One App Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vansteinengroentjes.prioritynumber)

My code Below:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);

    if (intent.getAction()!=null && intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")){

        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){

            audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, maxVolume/2, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On which device you are trying this? Also mention android device version

Comment: I try to support Android API 19 - 28, I test on Api 21 & 23 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working on something very similar. You actually have to play a ringtone after overriding the audio settings. But you only need to do this on Android 6.0+ Get an instance of the ringtone and play it when phone state is ringing else just stop it.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);

    Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, uri);

    if (intent.getAction()!=null && intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")){

        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){

        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, maxVolume/2, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);

        r.play();

        }else {

        r.stop();

        }
    }
}
```

Problems you'll run into with this implementation. You will get multiple ringtones playing because the onReceive method is called many times during Phone State changes. The provides a different context each time onReceive is called and creates a different instance of Ringtone each time. I launched a background service to fix this issue so I could hold a single reference to a context and thus a single reference to Ringtone.

Comment: Yeah, I already solved this. But you are absolutely right answere. I use service to stop the ringtone as well. I tested this in android 6.0 and works perfectly. Are you sure this won't work below 6.0?

Comment: It does work below android 6.0, but I haven’t needed to create a ringtone and play it for versions below 6.0. Changing audio manager has been enough for my cases. I know you already solved, but if this is correct, can you please accept and award bounty?

Comment: And you told you are done about similar project. have you some time to talk about some other thing about this project? If you are busy then it's ok, don't mind bro.

Comment: For `Do Not Disturb` mode how you handle this? for change `Do Not Disturb` to any other mode app got crash. Though I'm not try to find but planning to find the solution. But if you can help me that'll save my time.

Comment: I'll have some time throughout the week to discuss what I've done. I'll send you a message on Twitter and we can go from there. Sound good?

Comment: Yeah, That will be great.

Answer (score 1):

Some devices may not have volume control and may operate at a fixed volume, and may not enable muting or changing the volume of audio streams.

[isVolumeFixed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isVolumeFixed())

This method will return true on such devices.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But It's not my issue solution and I already find my solution.

Comment: @HasibAkter Can you please post your solution and mark it as solved to help others?